# fgrep or grep -F, which one is better for portable script?

Tags: grep, posix

I am having this controversial commentary on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483866/3744681) to a quesion whether we should use [fgrep](/questions/tagged/fgrep) or [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) with the `-F` switch (i.e `grep -F`) for portability. The points that have been came into light so far are:

`grep -F`:

- Is a POSIX Standard.
- GNU `grep` has declared `fgrep` to be deprecated.

`fgrep`:

- Historically it came before the `grep -F` option.
- Even though GNU grep declared `fgrep` to be deprecated, they seem to stick with it for it's historical use.

If you consider old (really old) systems, then probably you can find some of them not having the `grep -F` in them (and I think the chance of it happening is very rare). But do we really need to worry about those very very old machines and avoid POSIX standard for that!!

If you think about the current situation and include those old machines (which supposedly/allegedly doesn't have `grep -F`), then the systems supporting `fgrep` will be more.

On the other hand, if you look into the future, `fgrep` is going to be a history and `grep -F` will triumph upon it as a POXIS standard.

And moreover isn't it a general knowledge now, to use POSIX standard for better portability?

Comment: Same question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490686/fgrep-or-grep-f-which-one-is-better-for-portable-script . Please do not cross post.

Comment: @Celada that post is going to be closed soon, it's kinda off-fopic there.

Comment: In that case, please delete it and don't create extra work for everybody.

Answer (score 6):

`grep -F` is POSIX. `fgrep` is not. Use `grep -F` and make it clear that your script depends on a POSIX `grep`. Clearly stated dependencies are all you need.

I guess you could use both...

```sh
if    command -v fgrep 
then  _grepf(){ fgrep "$@"; }
else  _grepf(){ grep -F "$@"; }
fi    >/dev/null
```

...but doing stuff like that is hacky and usually a waste of time. Set a minimum-level of conformance in your dependency list and allow the standard to handle the rest.